# Argument(s) are different! Wanted:

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am writing a unit test for my below code

```
public class Class1 {
   protected void execute(String a, String b) {
   try{
      process(a,b);
   }
   catch(Exception E){
       Class2.write(e,Class1.class.getSimpleName())
    }
  }

  private void process(String a, String b) {
     validate(a,b);
     // Doing some processing on a and b values
  }

 private void validate (String a, String b) {
    if(a==null || a.isEmpty() || b==null || b.isEmpty())
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input value cannot be null or empty");
 }

}
```

For the above code, I am trying to write a UT which covers the exception use case. Below is my UT code,

```
@Test

public void test1(){
 try {

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class2.class);
            PowerMockito.when(Class2.class, "write", Mockito.anyObject(), Mockito.anyString())
                    .thenCallRealMethod();
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            Class2.write(new IllegalArgumentException("Input value cannot be null or empty"),Class1.class.getSimpleClassName());
            PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Class2.class, VerificationModeFactory.times(1));
            class1.execute(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString());  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

I am getting the below exception when I execute the above test

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
Class2.write{
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Input value cannot be null or empty,
Class1
}

Actual invocation has different arguments:
Class2.write{
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Input value cannot be null or empty,
Class1
}
```

Can someone please help me on resolving this issue?
I really appreciate your help and time

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Your Problem:

`IllegalArgumentException` does not use the string message for equality. It would be safer to test the string message or the class type. I would prefer that the test detect the type rather than the message, as the string message should not be used for control flow, it is an implementation detail.

```
System.out.println(Objects.equals(
    new IllegalArgumentException(), 
    new IllegalArgumentException()));
// false

System.out.println(Objects.equals(
    new IllegalArgumentException().getClass(),
    new IllegalArgumentException().getClass()));
// true
```

So to mock this I would use matchers:

```
any(IllegalArgumentException.class), eq(Class1.class.getSimpleName())
```

---

#### Issues with your design:

I'm going to end with an argument against how this code is structured, being that it is not built around dependency injection. Rather than calling the static method `Class2::write`, you could be calling an instance method.

For example, create the interface:

```
public interface Writer {
    void write(Exception e, String source);
}
```

You can now refactor the class to provide two ctors, one that accepts any writer, and one that defaults to `Class2`.

```
public class Class1 {
    private final Writer writer;

    public Class1() {
        this(Class2::write);
    }

    public Class1(Writer writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    protected void execute(String a, String b) {
        try {
            process(a,b);
        }
        catch (Exception E) {
            writer.write(e, Class1.class.getSimpleName());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Using this strategy you can now simply create an instance mock of `Writer`. This avoids having to mock as static method which changes the bytecode of your application, and also make your class more flexible as it can support many different writer implementations now. Anything that is modifying the bytecode of the application should be used very sparingly, such as replacing static method calls, does not truly validate the runtime execution of your code.

In my opinion, the majority of the PowerMockito/PowerMock only help verify code which was not built with testability / flexibility in mind. You shouldn't need to use anything outside of the Mockito/EasyMock tool-set for well structured code. There are some exceptions but the tool-set should be used very sparingly.